# Using PHP to prettify text

Tags: php

I am building a web interface for our customers to view orders etc.

Internal order system saves text strings in the database that I'm using in CAPITALS (don't ask).

So for example `$row['PO_NUMBER']` shows `900800 AN ORDER NUMBER`.

I want to create a simple function to prettify this so that I can use `prettify($row['PO_NUMBER']);` and that would show as `900800 An Order Number` instead.

Is this possible?

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is asking about **possibilities** and **is not a concrete coding question**. If you want to know if something is possible you should **research it** and **attempt to implement it**. If you have issues while doing this you then can ask a **specific** question, **showing the code you have written**, your expected results, and your actual results. [Question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: How is this difficult? `ucwords(strtolower($row['AUF_NR']));` [Link to functioning example](http://ideone.com/xgIvmI)

Comment: Can u please show us the code which you have written

Comment: Why bother even changing it with PHP if it's just to prettify some onscreen display? You can do the same thing with CSS `text-transform`

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
<?php 
function prettify($string){
    $temp = explode(' ',$string); //Get each words in the string
    foreach($temp as key => $value){
        $temp[$key] = ucfirst($value); //Set first letter as a capital letter
    }
    return implode(' ',$temp); //Recompose the string and return the value
}
?>
```

Comment: Why? this is so overly complex, you could just do `function prettify($string){ return ucwords(strtolower($string)); })`

Answer (score 0):

```
function prettify($string){
    return ucwords(strtolower($string));
}
```